# Wedge of 5 circles is a covering space of wedge of wedge of two circles?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I was going through some problems on covering spaces and [here](https://subhadipchowdhury.github.io/assets/problemsets/2015WOMP.pdf) Exrecise 5.4(B) asks if wedge of $4$ circles is a covering space of wedge of $2$ circles. I am sure it is.

Now I am curious if wedge of $5$ circles is a covering space of wedge of $2$ circles?

In general, is it true that if wedge of $m$ circles is a covering of wedge of $n$ circles, then $n|m$. I am sure the converse holds but what about this?

Comment: The wedge of three or more circles can never cover $S^1\vee S^1$. If there were a covering map, then that map must be a local homeomorphism, but then there would be an issue with the wedge point.

Comment: @Kevin.S In this particular case, can I say that if $p$ is a covering map, then we have a neighborhood of $0$, such that $p_{|U}$ is a homeomorphism onto $p(U)$ but $U\setminus \{0\}$ has $10$ connected components but $p_{|U}\setminus\{p(0)\}$ can have maximum $4$ which is a contradiction?

Comment: That's one way to prove it. Another is to use the fundamental group.

Comment: how to prove using fundamental group?

Comment: Hint: if $p:X\rightarrow Y$ is a covering map, then $p_*$ is an injection between the fundamental groups.

Comment: First ,These two spaces are different. Secondly Do you mean I have to show that the fundamental group of $S^1 \vee S^1\vee S^1\vee S^1\vee S^1$ is not a subgroup of fundamental group of $S^1 \vee S^1$. Honestly I do not know how to show that free group on $5$ generators isn't contained in free group of $2$ generators

Comment: and I am alos curious to know when exactly free group on $m$ generators is isomorphic to a subgroup of free group on $n$ generators.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess about divisibility is almost right but slightly off. The Euler characteristic of the wedge of $n$ circles is $1 - n$; by the multiplicativity of Euler characteristic in covers this means that if the wedge of $m$ circles covers the wedge of $n$ circles *up to homotopy* then $n - 1 \mid m - 1$, and this turns out to be an if-and-only if. In particular

- the free group $F_m$ is a subgroup of the free group $F_n$ iff $n-1 \mid m-1$,
- the wedge of $m$ circles covers the wedge of $2$ circles up to homotopy for any $m \ge 2$, but
- this is not the intended point of the exercise, because the exercise doesn't ask for a covering space up to homotopy but a covering space on the nose. And a $d$-fold covering space of a graph must be a graph with $d$ times as many edges and vertices. So the wedge of $m$ circles can't literally cover the wedge of $n$ circles for $m \neq n$ even if the Euler characteristic works out.